# Cloning a javascript object that has a callback doesn't execute the callback method

Tags: javascript

I have a component where I am defining two objects with default properties, one of which is a callback method.

I am then trying to clone/assign that default object to another variable that my getter is using. Doing this, however, the callback method is never run when the button it is attached to is clicked.

Both `object.assign` and `spread` were things I attempted as well, but I may be approaching this incorrectly.

**Example code:**

```
// defaults
DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER = {
    cb: this._modalSaveHandler,
    label: "Create Case",
    variant: "brand",
    action: "createcase",
    class: "",
    disabled: true,
    visible: true
  };
  DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER = {
    cb: this._modalCancelHandler,
    label: "Cancel",
    variant: "netrual",
    class: "btn-left",
    action: "close",
    disabled: false,
    visible: true
  };

  // Set vars for getter
  _save = this.DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER;
  _cancel = this.DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER;

  /* Spread Attempt
  _save = { ... this.DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER };
  _cancel = { ... this.DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER};
  */

 /* Assign Attempt
  _save = Object.assign({}, this.DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER);
  _cancel = Object.assign({}, this.DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER);
  */


  // Getters
  get saveHandler() {
    return this._save
  }
  set saveHandler(props){
    this._save = Object.assign({}, this.DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER, props)
  }

  get cancelHandler() {
    return this._cancel
  }
  set cancelHandler(props) {
    this._cancel = Object.assign({}, this.DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER, props)
  }


  // Callbacks
  _modalSaveHandler = () => {
    console.log("save handler ran");
  };

  _modalCancelHandler = () => {
    console.log("cancel handler ran");
  };

  // Some random method to update a property on the button
  onButtonClick(){
      this.saveHandler = { disabled: false };
  }
```

Now when my other component tries to run the callback method I am attempting to pass, it is not hitting it at all.

Is this an issue with a scope or my misunderstanding of how the properties are being cloned/referenced?

**UPDATE:**

When changing the default object to contain the callback function directly, it works fine.

It seems like the issue happens when trying to reference the callback method versus inline.

```
DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER = {
    //cb: this._modalCancelHandler,
    cb: () => {
      console.log('this works')
    },
    label: "Cancel",
    variant: "netrual",
    class: "btn-left",
    action: "close",
    disabled: false,
    visible: true
  };
```

Comment: Doubt this has anything to do with the cloning. Perhaps you need to change your callbacks to `cb: this._modalSaveHandler.bind(this)`

Comment: Hm, thanks @Phil I gave that a try but it threw an error of `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) if you want to reference keys of the object you are just declaring.

Without the getter, the handler on the original object is already undefined, hence it's not cloned.

```js
const obj = {
  _handler() {
    console.log('foo')
  },
  get handler() {
    return this._handler
  }
}

const clone = { ...obj }

obj.handler()

clone.handler()
```

Note, that you should not use arrow functions for this because the `this` keyword will not work the same when doing so.

Comment: So this works if the function is defined directly in the property like so: `_cb: () => { console.log('blah') }, get cb() { return this._cb }`. But why can't I reference a fat arrow function from a property and have it work the same way such as `cb: this._modalSaveHandler`?

Comment: Arrow functions don't carry the `this` in the same way regular functions do. 'It's a common pitfall to try to use arrow function in classes such as vue components for example. Or now in your case, it's the same pitfall. As rule of thumb, whenever you work with `this`, just stay away from arrows functions and safe yourself headache over nothing but syntax in that case. I found some article about it with a quick web search https://dev.to/shubham57396755/arrow-functions-and-this-keyword-1kg7

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a class where your code resides and when you create DEFAULT_OBJECTS the callback functions are undefined.

Try to move callback declaration higher than `DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER` and `DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER`

Like:

```js
  // Callbacks
  _modalSaveHandler = () => {
    console.log("save handler ran");
  };

  _modalCancelHandler = () => {
    console.log("cancel handler ran");
  };

  // defaults
  DEFAULT_SAVE_HANDLER = {
    cb: this._modalSaveHandler,
    label: "Create Case",
    variant: "brand",
    action: "createcase",
    class: "",
    disabled: true,
    visible: true
  };
  DEFAULT_CANCEL_HANDLER = {
    cb: this._modalCancelHandler,
    label: "Cancel",
    variant: "netrual",
    class: "btn-left",
    action: "close",
    disabled: false,
    visible: true
  };

  //....
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work? Wouldn't the callback functions be hoisted to the top already? The fact that this does work just prompts me to ask why.

Comment: I see that you are referencing this, so I made the assumption that this code is in a class. Functions were not hoisted because they are not functions, but class fields.